# Requirement already satisfied: mysql-python in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Tags: python, mysql

I am writing a program that imports MySQLdb in PyCharm, but it reports that "No Module Named MySQLdb".

I googled and tried many solutions within stackoverflow. However, it has not been solved.

When I run the command "pip install MySQL-python", the terminal reports "Requirement already satisfied: MySQL-python in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages", and MySQL-python indeed exits there.

How could the PyCharm successfully find and import MySQLdb ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be the problem with your PyCharm Interpreter. Go to PyCharm-Preferences-Project Interpreter, choose Python 2.7, which is the version that you installed. Make sure the package that you are looking for is on the list of installed packages below.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have installed two versions of Python on the mac. After switching to the one that includes MySQLdb, the problem is solved.

Comment: Nice, I'm glad that helped. Good luck!